# concat the strings of one column based on condition on other column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame that I want to remove duplicates on column named "sample"  and the add string information in gene and status columns to new column as shown in the attached pics.

Thank you so much  in advance

[image]

below is the modified version of data frame.where gene in rows are replaced by actual gene names[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here, `df` is your Pandas DataFrame.

```
def new_1(g):
    return ','.join(g.gene)

def new_2(g):
    return ','.join(g.gene + '-' + g.status)    

new_1_data = df.groupby("sample").apply(new_1).to_frame(name="new_1")
new_2_data = df.groupby("sample").apply(new_2).to_frame(name="new_2")

new_data = pd.merge(new_1_data, new_2_data, on="sample")
new_df = pd.merge(df, new_data, on="sample").drop_duplicates("sample")
```

If you wish to have "sample" as a column instead of an index, then add

```
new_df = new_df.reset_index(drop=True)
```

Lastly, as you did not specify which of the original rows of duplicates to retain, I simply use the default behavior of Pandas and drop all but the first occurrence.

### Edit

I converted your example to the following CSV file (delimited by ',') which I will call "data.csv".

```
sample,gene,status
ppar,p53,gain
ppar,gata,gain
ppar,nb,loss
srty,nf1,gain
srty,cat,gain
srty,cd23,gain
tygd,brac1,loss
tygd,brac2,gain
tygd,ras,loss
```

I load this data as

```
# Default delimiter is ','. Pass `sep` argument to specify delimiter.
df = pd.read_csv("data.csv")
```

Running the code above and printing the dataframe produces the output

```
  sample   gene status            new_1                           new_2
0   ppar    p53   gain      p53,gata,nb      p53-gain,gata-gain,nb-loss
3   srty    nf1   gain     nf1,cat,cd23     nf1-gain,cat-gain,cd23-gain
6   tygd  brac1   loss  brac1,brac2,ras  brac1-loss,brac2-gain,ras-loss
```

This is exactly the expected output given in your example.

Note that the left-most column of numbers (0, 3, 6) are the remnants of the index of the original dataframes produced after the merges. When you write this dataframe to file you can exclude it by setting `index=False` for `df.to_csv(...)`.

### Edit 2

I checked the CSV file you emailed me. **You have a space after the word "gene" in the header of your CSV file**.

Change the first line of your CSV file from

```
sample,gene ,status
```

to

```
sample,gene,status
```

Also, there are spaces in your entries. If you wish to remove them, you can

```
# Strip spaces from entries. Only works for string entries
df = df.applymap(lambda x: x.strip())
```

Comment: Thanks.  The program is looking for gene in the rows and gives me    key error when I use real gene names . Actually gene1 and gene2 are examples. gene1 in reality is  TP53, gene2 in reality is GATA, gene3 in reality is WNT.   how should I modify the code to make it work? thanks

Comment: AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'gene'

Comment: @Sasihci The code should still work even if "gene1", "gene2" etc. are replaced by their actual name. Make sure that your pandas DataFrame has the 3 columns "sample", "gene", and "status". In your new example, make sure your CSV file has 3 columns, 1 for each of these 3 attributes, and make sure you use the correct delimiter. If possible, give a small sample (a few rows would do) of the text (not an image) in your file.

Comment: @Sasihci Like I said, the code looks for a **column** (**not** the values in the column) with the name "gene". The error is due to Pandas not finding such a column. So it shouldn't matter if you change the actual names of the genes in the dataframe. The error is most likely due to the format of your input file (and hence the way data is stored in your dataframe). Unless you provide more information (for e.g., part of the actual data), it is difficult to provide a fix.

Comment: thanks. its embarrassing , I am doing exactly the same thing it is not working. is it ok to email you the test.tsv and my ipython notebook ? what is is your email ? thanks

Comment: @Sasihci See my latest edit. The problem is with your CSV file's header row.

Comment: @Sasihci Please mark this as the answer by clicking the "tick" next to it.

Comment: I clicked your answer but it wasn't recording since  I have only 14 points. I need to have at least 15 to record my click. I will comeback to click your answer once I have 15 points.

Comment: No worries :). The "tick" is below the downvote icon. I also added some additional comments on spaces in your data and a slight change to the function `new_2` which can speed things up if your dataframe is large.

Answer (score 1):

Might not be the most efficient solution but this should get you there:

```
        samples = []
        genes= []
        statuses = []

        for s in set(df["sample"]):
            #grab unique samples
            samples.append(s)

            #get the genes for each sample and concatenate them
            g = df["gene"][df["sample"]==s].str.cat(sep=",")
            genes.append(g)

            #loop through the genes for the sample and get the statuses
            status = ''
            for gene in g.split(","):
                gene_status = df["status"][(df["sample"] == s) & (df["gene"] == gene)].to_string(index=False)

                status += gene
                status += "-"
                status += gene_status
                status += ','

            statuses.append(status)

        #create new df
        new_df = pd.DataFrame({'sample': samples,
                               'new': genes,
                               'new1': statuses})
```